# How to abstract over bounded type parameters in Scala?

Tags: scala, generics

Say I am working on a project that has `A <: Foo with Bar[A] with Baz[A]` in every function definition, like the following:

```
def listSomething[A <: Foo with Bar[A] with Baz[A]](query: String): List[A] = ???

def readSomething[A <: Foo with Bar[A] with Baz[A]](id: Long): Option[A]
```

Is it possible to remove this duplication? I tried to define a type alias but it didn't seem to work. The only working thing I could come up with was to treat them as abstract type members, but then I would have to turn functions into traits, and maybe there's a better way.

Comment: this type alias works for me in scala 2.13:  `type All[T] = Foo with Bar[T] with Baz[T]`

Comment: That might work but its not the same thing... You forget what the A specifically is there.  I'm wondering what the error is with `type[A <: Foo] = A with Bar[A] with Baz[A]`?  How exactly are you using this type?

Comment: @BogdanVakulenko This seems to work with the Scala version I'm using too. Thanks for this. I guess I'll just deal with the type constructor for now.

Comment: @Nigel Benns It's being used for lot's of things, but mainly as a constraint.

Comment: @NigelBenns `with Bar[A] with Baz[A]` in the question is a part of the bound, in your case it's not.

Answer (score 1):

```
trait Foo
trait Bar[A]
trait Baz[A]
trait All[A] extends Foo with Bar[A] with Baz[A]
def listSomething[S <: All[S]](query: String): List[S] = ???
```